# Using huggingface's accelerate with 2GPUs and throwed an error:RuntimeError: Expected to mark a variable ready only once

Tags: python, multi-gpu, huggingface

I want to train BigBird with 2gpus, and I use huggingface's accelerate in notebook,so I use notebook_launcher.

I have followed the example in https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/examples/accelerate/simple_nlp_example.ipynb

and added some extra code :

```
ddp_kwargs = DistributedDataParallelKwargs(find_unused_parameters=True)
accelerator = Accelerator(kwargs_handlers=[ddp_kwargs])
```

according to https://github.com/huggingface/accelerate/issues/24

because python threw an error:

`RuntimeError: Expected to have finished reduction in the prior iteration before starting a new one.`

after runing the code at first.But at second run, python also threw an error that:

`` RuntimeError: Expected to mark a variable ready only once. This error is caused by one of the following reasons: 1) Use of a module parameter outside the `forward` function. Please make sure model parameters are not shared across multiple concurrent forward-backward passes. or try to use _set_static_graph() as a workaround if this module graph does not change during training loop.2) Reused parameters in multiple reentrant backward passes. For example, if you use multiple `checkpoint` functions to wrap the same part of your model, it would result in the same set of parameters been used by different reentrant backward passes multiple times, and hence marking a variable ready multiple times. DDP does not support such use cases in default. You can try to use _set_static_graph() as a workaround if your module graph does not change over iterations. Parameter at index 99 has been marked as ready twice. This means that multiple autograd engine  hooks have fired for this particular parameter during this iteration. You can set the environment variable TORCH_DISTRIBUTED_DEBUG to either INFO or DETAIL to print parameter names for further debugging. ``

I don't know how to deal with it, then I began my targetless exploring and found that setting `model.transformer.gradient_checkpointing_disable()` after initializing the model would complete some forward loops,but it always dead in the 11th step even 25 minutes had past.

Here is my training function and could anyone helps me find the error in my code out so that my code can run through a epoch? Thanks in advance!(*^_^*)

```
def training_function():
    ddp_kwargs = DistributedDataParallelKwargs(find_unused_parameters=True)
    accelerator = Accelerator(kwargs_handlers=[ddp_kwargs])
    if accelerator.is_main_process:
        datasets.utils.logging.set_verbosity_warning()
        transformers.utils.logging.set_verbosity_info()
    else:
        datasets.utils.logging.set_verbosity_error()
        transformers.utils.logging.set_verbosity_error()
    set_seed(hyperparameters['seed'])
    global tokenizer
    tokenizer = JiebaTokenizer.from_pretrained('Lowin/chinese-bigbird-small-1024')
    model = BB(hyperparameters)
    # model.transformer.gradient_checkpointing_disable()
    optimizer = optim.AdamW(params=model.parameters(),lr=1e-5,weight_decay=1e-2)
    
    dataSetTrain = DS(trains,tokenizer,hyperparameters)
    dataSetValid = DS(valida,tokenizer,hyperparameters)
    tDL = DataLoader(dataSetTrain,batch_size=hyperparameters['batch_size_train'],shuffle=True)
    vDL = DataLoader(dataSetValid,batch_size=hyperparameters['batch_size_valid'])
    
    model,optimizer,tDL,vDL = accelerator.prepare(
        model,optimizer,tDL,vDL
    )
    num_epochs = hyperparameters["epoch"]
    progress_bar = tqdm(range(num_epochs * len(tDL)), disable=not accelerator.is_main_process)

    rouge = load_metric('rouge')
    step = 0
    epochs = hyperparameters['epoch']
    vocab_size = hyperparameters['vocab_size']
    accumulate_setp = hyperparameters['accumulate_setp']
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        model.train()
        for batch in tDL:
            step += 1
            labels = batch.pop('labels')
            logits = model(batch)
            loss_sum = F.cross_entropy(logits.view(-1,vocab_size),labels.view(-1),reduction='sum')
            title_length = labels.ne(0).sum().item()
            loss = loss_sum/title_length
            loss = loss/accumulate_setp
            accelerator.backward(loss)
            
            if step % accumulate_setp == 0:
                # torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 2)
                optimizer.step()
                optimizer.zero_grad()
            progress_bar.update(1)
            writer.add_scalar('Loss',loss,step)  # 将损失写入tensorboard，便于观察loss变化
        if epoch % 5 == 0:
            allIndexes = []
            allLabels = []
            with torch.no_grad():
                model.eval()
                for sample in vDL:
                    label = sample.pop('labels')
                    logits = model(sample)

                    logits = logits[0]
                    assert len(logits.shape) == 2

                    index = logits.argmax(dim=1)
                    index = index>0  # 获取token_id不为0的所有token 所在的输出向量的索引
                    index = logits[index].argmax(dim=1)

                    label = label[label!=0]

                    allIndexes.append(index)
                    allLabels.append(label)
                result = rouge.compute(predictions=allIndexes,references=allLabels)
                rouge1Recall = result['rouge1'][1][1]
                rouge2Recall = result['rouge2'][1][1]
                rougeLRecall = result['rougeL'][1][1]
                accelerator.print(f'epoch{epoch}: rouge1:{rouge1Recall} rouge2:{rouge2Recall} rougeL:{rougeLRecall}')

    writer.close()
    accelerator.print('Final result:\n',result)
```